# I want to block using any application of computer, when my web application is using

Tags: php, linux, windows, web-applications

I am developing an on-line examination portal. I want to block accessing/using of all other application, when the candidates attending exams. I know, we ca not control a computer only with browser's client side scripting. Is any other option for achieving my requirement [Any applications that can be called with JavaScript or anything like that].

Comment: Pretty close to impossible using modern day operating systems that are designed to be multi-tasking..... you'd need to have absolute control over the user's computer..... which is very bad for security... and is why examination centres use custom computers rather than allowing users to have their own computer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But some companies conducting on-line exam for recruitment process, and they are doing as, what my need. And it is for conducting exams internally in an organization.

Comment: So they would be installing the software on their own computers?  That would make it possible in principle, I think - or, rather, you probably can't entirely stop people from switching to another application, but it might be possible to detect them doing it.  I expect you'd be best off including the client end of the portal as part of the same piece of software rather than using a web browser.  But I fear this question may be too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mark Baker And Harry Johnston said It is impossible to do such thing in your browser.You can't control other applications using your browser.Maybe you can control your website or even your browser by code but not any other application.